# Chrome Headless Doesn't work

Tags: google-chrome, headless-browser, google-chrome-headless

I've read about the Chrome Headless from [developers.google](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) said we can run the Google without UI. Quote from that link :

> Headless Chrome is shipping in Chrome 59. It's a way to run the Chrome
>   browser in a headless environment. Essentially, running Chrome without
>   chrome! It brings all modern web platform features provided by
>   Chromium and the Blink rendering engine to the command line.
>
> Why is that useful?
>
> A headless browser is a great tool for automated testing and server
>   environments where you don't need a visible UI shell. For example, you
>   may want to run some tests against a real web page, create a PDF of
>   it, or just inspect how the browser renders an URL.

This is really great feature, so I do some experiment with this cool feature. The idea is to taking snapshot as the document site by do call of chrome.exe from Windows Command Prompt, as follow :

```
chrome --headless --disable-gpu --screenshot https://www.chromestatus.com/
```

After do several times and following the instruction from these site. I got **nothing**. I don't get any picture or screenshot with name `screenshot.png` as document mention it before `Running with --screenshot will produce a file named screenshot.png in the current working directory.`

From this document also said about version,

> Caution: Headless mode is available on Mac and Linux in Chrome 59.
>   Windows support is coming in Chrome 60. To check what version of
>   Chrome you have, open chrome://version.

after do some check with suggested before, I run `chrome://version` on my Chrome on Windows x64 Machine and got some result :

```
Google Chrome   62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: Stable)
Revision    4fd852a98d66564c88736c017b0a0b0478e885ad-refs/branch-heads/3202@{#789}
```

What wrong? What i missed? 
Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After do some experiments. for `--screenshot` will save the image on the same level as chrome.exe location and that will be mean save on `Program Files`.

So we need need to combine parameter names and arguments with a =

--screenshot="D:\screen.png" will work, otherwise Chrome writes to it's installation folder. Big design flaw, no software should use it's installation folder as a working directory.

Here are the complete argument :

```
chrome --headless --enable-logging --disable-gpu --screenshot="D:\screen.png" "https://www.chromestatus.com/"
```

Comment: As per https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome#printing_the_dom_dom the screenshot is saved in the home directory which is the chrome installation directory, if you run it from there